# change the value of one row with another row in same table using sql

Tags: sql

I have table like this .

```
   code  |     name
-------+--------------- 
   102 |    chennai
   101 |    delhi
```

I want to change the code of chennai as 101 and delhi as 102. How can I do this?

Comment: It is bad idea to change `id` of the entity.

Comment: its not id i simply specified name as id

Comment: It's a bad idea to think of an number as something that makes a entity unique.

Comment: Do you have any relationships with this table? Which RDBMS are you use?

Answer (score 1):

```
update table1 set code = 103 where code = 102;

update table1 set code = 102 where code = 101;

update table1 set code = 101 where code = 103;
```

Or you can use [CURSOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28databases%29)

Comment: with help of joins how to change this?

Comment: @marc_s: yeah, if you want play safe, use cursor

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no foreign key, the table name is city, the city name is unique and the database is mysql.
You can use the same concept for other databases. 
 1. Drop the index.
 2. Update the values
 3. Recreate the index

```
CREATE TABLE `city` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

alter table city drop primary key;
update city, (
    select 101 as id, 'chennai' as name
    union all
    select 102 as id, 'delhi' as name
) newIDs
set city.id = newIDs.id
where city.name = newIDS.name ;
alter table city add primary key (id);
```